# Is destroying a persistent record in a `before_validation` callback bad code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I want to prevent reports where the values of `distributed` && `checked` are both nil || zero from being created.

I also want users to be able to delete existing reports by setting these values to either nil or zero in the form (reports are created and edited in batches and the UX leans towards setting the value to 0 or deleting the values from the form instead of a 'delete' button).

As a hobbyist, something about this feels like a bad idea:

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  before_validation :prevent_meaningless_reports, if: (distributed.nil? || distributed.zero?) && (checked.nil? || checked.zero?)
  ...

  ...

  private

  def prevent_meaningless_reports
    if new_record?
      throw :abort
    else #persisted?
      self.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

It feels bad to be destroying a record during a `before_*` callback.

I'm risking asking a potentially opinion-based question because it seems like I might be violating some software principle that would tell me why this is a bad idea.

If this is acceptable behavior, is it better to do this in two blocks, one for `before_create` (for new records) and one for `before_update` (for persistent records)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you'll run into with this is when you trying to update a meaningless_report that already exists to perform further operations on it.

E.g:

```
meaningless_report.update(attribute: some_value)

meaningless_report.some_other_value #meaningless_report is already removed from the db and frozen
```

If you try to update the meaningless_report object again, you'll run into a RuntimeError. So this is definitely not a good idea

A better option is to use ActiveRecord validations, such that even before the reports are created, we validate them to ensure they are not meaningless and also ensure the records don't become meaningless during updates

E.g:

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord

  validate :validate_meaningful_reports

  def not_meaningful_report?
    (distributed.nil? || distributed.zero?) && (checked.nil? || checked.zero?)
  end

  private

  def validate_meaningful_reports
   if not_meaningful_report?
     errors.add(:base, "Report violates validations")
   end
  end


end
```

With this, we ensure that no meaningless report is created. To handle old meaningless reports, we can use a script or maybe a rake task for this. The script/task can look like this:

```
 meaningless_reports = Report.unscoped.find_each { |r| r.destroy if r.not_meaningful_report?}
```

This is much safer

Comment: That last code would be much better if you passed a block to `.find_each` and did `.find_each { |r| r.destroy if r.not_meaningful_report? }` as that will load the records in batches while select will load everything when you pass a block.

Comment: You're right, record reloading was the piece I wasn't thinking about.